# Setting layout to a Popup contentview Android

Tags: android

I created a Popupview

```
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
```

then I try to set the `contentview` with the XML layout file of newpup_up, but I am getting an error here "**Rename in File**" what does that mean?

pw.setContentView(R.layout.newpop_up);

Comment: it's a runtime error or a compiler error?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in your layout to the constructor directly.

```
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(R.layout.newpop_up);
```